# Mongodb : I used db.shutdownServer() but connections increased

Tags: mongodb

In my terminal, I used db.shutdownServer() to restart the server.( and I also tried Ctrl+C to terminate.)

but after when I typed "sudo mongod", last connections are still alived and even more increased.

Like this...

```
0.1:63292 #46 (46 connections now open)
2015-06-23T20:49:25.249+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63293 #47 (47 connections now open)
2015-06-23T20:49:25.250+0900 I NETWORK  [conn47] end connection 127.0.0.1:63293 (46 connections now open)
2015-06-23T20:49:25.253+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63294 #48 (47 connections now open)
2015-06-23T20:49:25.254+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63295 #49 (48 connections now open)
2015-06-23T20:49:25.254+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63296 #50 (49 connections now open)
2015-06-23T20:49:25.254+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63297 #51 (50 connections now open)
2015-06-23T20:49:25.254+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63298 #52 (51 connections now open)
2015-06-23T20:49:36.257+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63300 #53 (52 connections now open)
```

what is the problem?? Please let me know the reason. Thank you !

Comment: From your description it's not clear if the server actually successfully shutdown or what the problem is. If the connections are increasing there must be an application still making new connections to MongoDB. What messages do you get after `db.shutdownServer()`? Did you run this command from the `admin` database?